# Search TextFile for Line with a specific string

Tags: delphi

Is it possible to search a TextFile line by line to find a specific string.
ie. Hello
It searches line by line to find if any line has Hello in it. There will only be one string per line.
Is this possible?
If so how do I attempt this?

Comment: Are you prepared to load the entire file into memory, or do you need to load it in smaller chunks?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's certainly easiest to load the entire file into memory. Provided that your file is small enough then you can do it like this:

```
found := false;
sl := TStringList.Create;
try
  sl.LoadFromFile(fileName);
  for line in sl do
    if Pos('Hello', line)<>0 then
    begin
      found := true;
      break;
    end;
finally
  sl.Free;
end;
```

I assume that when you say

> if any line has Hello in it

that you are looking for lines that contain the search string rather than lines that equal the search string.

---

In a comment you ask:

> Ok can I then ask if it would be possible to ask on how to
>   delete a string that is typed from an edit box out of a file? So
>   you enter a string into an edit box then it searches the file
>   for it and deletes that line?

That's an easy enough variation of the above:

```
procedure RemoveLinesContaining(const fileName, searchText: string);
var
  sl: TStringList;
  i: Integer;
begin
  sl := TStringList.Create;
  try
    sl.LoadFromFile(fileName);
    for i := sl.Count-1 downto 0 do
      if Pos(searchText, sl[i])<>0 then
        sl.Delete(i);
    sl.SaveToFile(fileName);
  finally
    sl.Free;
  end;
end;
```

This function deletes **all** lines that contain the search string. If you only want to delete the first such line, then break out of the for loop after the call to Delete.

The loop variable is descending to allow the loop to modify the list.

If you want to use a different test, say equality rather than contains, then simply modify the if statement.

Comment: +1 for the assumption which is probably right but which I missed when reading the question.

Answer (score 1):

An easy way is to use `TStringList.LoadFromFile` to load the file, then check `IndexOf('hello')` - if it's greater than `-1`, the string is in the file.

```
var
  sl : TStringList;
  ix : Integer;
begin
  sl := TStringList.Create;
  try      
    sl.LoadFromFile('test.txt'); 
    ix := sl.IndexOf('Hello');
    if ix > -1 then ShowMessage('Yup, the file contains a greeting.');
  finally 
    sl.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Ok can I then ask if it would be possible to ask on how to delete a string that is typed from an edit box out of a file.
So you enter a string into an edit box then it searches the file for it and deletes that line?

Comment: You run out of memory if the file is really big (: @MattBiggs you should answer the comment from David on your question first.

Comment: @Matt You can ask that if you want. But not in a comment. That's a new question. Or perhaps an edit to this one.

Comment: @Jeroen (and David) What do you think is the percentage of text files that will not fit into memory? I think we can assume that this is not an issue unless the OP states otherwise in the question. This discussion is not useful IMHO. Linear search through such a large text file would be incredibly slow anyhow.

Comment: Over the last year or two I've been doing a lot of text file work with most files being at least a couple of 100 megabytes in size. YMMV.

Comment: Then you are left with copying. If exact byte-to-byte copying is not needed (i mean CR/LF/CR+LF issue) - then he'd have to make old-fashioned pascal loop with ReadLn/WriteLn.  However i don;'t remember now whether EOF #26 char would prematurely cancel file reading, but it is low chance that in truly text file that symbol would met. @Matt - search help for topics: TextFile, AssignFile, Reset, CloseFile and ReadLn with WriteLN. You would copy file into new file line by line except one, then remove old file and rename new file. In that order.

Comment: This method is assuming the entire line is "Hello". The question is asking if a line *contains* "Hello".

Comment: @Jerry I interpreted "There will only be one string per line" to mean that the whole line could be matched. You may be right though.